# Discord.js Covid Tracker command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I recently created a bot and I want it to have a covid case tracker but it won't work when I try to use the command, it works doing `!covid` but won't work when I add a country name since it needs one.
Can anyone help me?

```js
const { prefix } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
    name: "covid",
    aliases: [],
    description: "case...",
    cooldown: 0,
    guildOnly: false,
    args: false,
    execute(message, args) {
        if (!args[0]) return message.reply("you need to enter a country name");
        const url = `https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/${args[0]}`;
        require(url, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) return msg.reply("err");
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            msg.reply(`Meow meow (Body case): + \*\*${body.cases}\*\*\ `);
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Can you give as some more information? Is the country in your `args` property? Does the API return any errors or any errors coming from your Javascript? So in your case, what does "does not work" mean? Pleas add any additional information to you question

Comment: I seems like you expect "require" to fetch the url which is not what it does.
What require is: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/
What (I think) you want to do: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

Comment: so, to use the command you need to do !covid <country> when i use !covid without country it worked and say you need to type a country, when i do !covid germany it give an error, the error said command not define @Hoargarth